Lookup Skew : Financial Account and Product Name in FSC package
I understand the lookup skew concept.
In FSC(Financial Services) we have standard lookup of Product (FinServ__ProductName__c) on Financial Account (FinServ__FinancialAccount__c) object.
Now these FinServ__FinancialAccount__c can be in millions in an org and holding product information as lookup.
Now can this be also subjected to lookup skew? If yes, is this an issue in FSC core package?

FinServ is a managed package, right?  I am guessing that lookup skew will have the same effect here as if you had your own custom objects with millions of records.

Yes it's managed package. But our product table gets updated in off peak hours, once a day at midnight. And there are hardly 10-15 products. Do you think it will still cause row lock while updating products.

As long as you're not attempting to update the Product data at the same time as the Financial Account data, then no this shouldn't be an issue (at least in terms of Row-Locking). Being deliberate about the sequencing of which tables are being updated should reduce this risk. I've worked with clients before with millions of Financial Accounts and a limited number of Products, and we didn't face any row-locking issues during the nightly batch processing of Financial Accounts or when Products were updated.
